# R: Non-numeric argument to binary operator produced in Loglikelihood Estimation

Tags: r, glm, mle

I want try to find maximum likelihood estimator by using optim() function in R. I start with modelling the data with GLM model to compare the estimation with optim().

Here's my code

```
 d <- read.delim("http://dnett.github.io/S510/Disease.txt")

d$disease=factor(d$disease)
d$ses=factor(d$ses)
d$sector=factor(d$sector)
#str(d)

oreduced <- glm(disease~age+sector, family=binomial(link=logit), data=d)
summary(oreduced)

y<-as.matrix(d$disease)
x1<-as.matrix(d$age)
x2<-as.matrix(d$sector)

nlldbin=function(param){
  eta<-param[1]+param[2]*x1+param[3]*x2
  p<-1/(1+exp(-eta))
  -sum(y*log(p)+(1-y)*log(1-p),na.rm=TRUE)
}
MLE_estimates<-optim(c(0.1,0.1,0.1),nlldbin,hessian=TRUE)
MLE_estimates
```

And the result is

```
Error in param[3] * x2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Can someone please kindly fix the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful when playing with factor variables. Sometimes, they act like strings and sometimes they act like numbers. The call to `as.matrix(d$disease)` treats `d$disease` like a string, giving you this nonsense output:

```
> head(y)
     [,1]
[1,] "0" 
[2,] "0" 
[3,] "0" 
[4,] "0" 
[5,] "1" 
[6,] "0"
```

What you wanted was probably this:

```
y<-as.numeric(as.character(d$disease))
x1<-as.numeric(as.character(d$age))
x2<-as.numeric(as.character(d$sector))

> head(y)
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

For more on this topic, I suggest section 8.2 of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). It's a bit out of date, but it will help.

Incidentially, if I'm not mistaken about your intentions, you may want to replace your penultimate line with this:

```
MLE_estimates<-optim(c(Intercept=0.1,age=0.1,sector2=0.1),nlldbin,hessian=TRUE)
```

it'll make the output easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
But the result is different between the estimate parameter from GLM and optim() package.
And I don't know why its different?

Comment: @JasmineHelen That's a theoretical question. Ask on Cross Validated.

Comment: @JasmineHelen The only difference that I'm noticing is in the intercept parameter. I wouldn't worry too much.